# How to make gnuplots fullscreen?

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

How can I make `gnuplot` plot its plots in full-screen instead of a small window?

Comment: Which operating system are you on?

Comment: @slhck On Ubuntu (running GTK, if that matters)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409071/how-to-open-gnuplots-in-full-screen-and-a-particular-size

Answer (score 1):

You can open use the `-geometry` option of gnuplot to supply the size of the window.

If you use gnuplot inside a script, you can do something like this:

```
resolution=$(xrandr | grep '*') && resolution=${resolution%  *}
gnuplot -persist -geometry $resolution << EOF
plot sin(x)
EOF
```

As an alternative you can make this alias in your `.bashrc` or whatever

```
alias gnuplotfs="resolution=\$(xrandr | grep '*') && resolution=\${resolution%  *} && gnuplot -geometry \$resolution"
```